# How can I execute parallel "for" loops in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing

I have been trying to parallelize the following script, specifically the for loop. How can I do that?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat /root/vms`;
do
    /usr/bin/sshpass -p 'test' /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
        -l testuser $i -t 'echo test | sudo -S yum update -y'
done
```

Comment: as you've written: *for loopS* - do you want to run multiple `for` loops in parallel? In that case you should specify the number of loops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
/usr/bin/sshpass ...
```

with

```
/usr/bin/sshpass ... &
```

Comment: here the thing is the for loop is executing serially. i want to execute the for loop in parallel.

Comment: That's what this change does. If your file /root/vms contains 20 lines this starts 20 sshpass parallel.

Comment: @gosatriani, how are you realizing your "*executing serially*"? Technically, this approach starts each command as background job, running in parallel

Answer (score 3):

You can do it quite succinctly with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel -a /root/vms /usr/bin/sshpass -p \'test\' /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l testuser {} -t \'echo test \| sudo -S yum update -y\'
```

So, if your `/root/vms` contains:

```
vm-ubuntuLTS
vm-centos
vm-debian
vm-arch
```

and you add the `--dry-run` option to see what it would do, without actually doing anything:

```
parallel --dry-run -a /root/vms /usr/bin/sshpass -p \'test\' /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l testuser {} -t \'echo test \| sudo -S yum update -y\'
```

**Sample Output**

```
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'test' /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l testuser vm-debian -t 'echo test | sudo -S yum update -y'
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'test' /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l testuser vm-centos -t 'echo test | sudo -S yum update -y'
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'test' /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l testuser vm-ubuntuLTS -t 'echo test | sudo -S yum update -y'
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'test' /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l testuser vm-arch -t 'echo test | sudo -S yum update -y'
```

---

Rather than repeating all your `ssh` options, consider putting them into a file at `$HOME/.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host vm-centos
HostName vm-centos
User freddy
   StrictHostKeyChecking no

Host vm-arch
HostName vm-arch
   User frog
   Port 2222
   ServerAliveInterval 10
```

Comment: when i use the above command, some syntax error is coming parallel: Warning: YOU ARE USING --tollef. IF THINGS ARE ACTING WEIRD USE --gnu.
parallel: Warning: --tollef is obsolete and will be retired 20140222.
parallel: Warning: See: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/parallel/2013-02/msg00018.html
/usr/bin/sshpass: vm-centos: command not found
-p: vm-centos: command not found
'test': vm-centos: command not found
/usr/bin/ssh: vm-centos: command not found
-o: vm-centos: command not found

Comment: It means your distro ships an old version of **GNU Parallel**. Either update it, or just use `parallel --gnu <OTHER OPTIONS>` Your version is from 2014.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel has a `--nonall` option and an environment variable to set the `ssh`-command to use:

```
PARALLEL_SSH="/usr/bin/sshpass -p test /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l testuser -t"
export PARALLEL_SSH
parallel --slf /root/vms --nonall 'echo test | sudo -S yum update -y'
```

If the things you want to run is a bit more complex, you can make a function and have GNU Parallel transfer that:

```
complex_task() {
  # Do complex task
  echo test | sudo -S yum update -y
  # and a lot more complex stuff
}
export -f complex_task
PARALLEL_SSH="/usr/bin/sshpass -p test /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l testuser -t"
export PARALLEL_SSH
parallel --slf /root/vms --env complex_task --nonall complex_task
```