# Run multiple clients at once

Tags: devops, benchmarking, query-performance, percona

I'm using the [Percona Query Playback tool](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/percona-playback-0-7-is-now-available/) and I want to run multiple clients at once

This is the sample command

```
/usr/local/bin/percona-playback --queue-depth 99999 --mysql-max-retries 0 --mysql-host somehost.xxx.com --mysql-username xxx --mysql-password xxxx --mysql-schema xxx --query-log-file some_slow_log.log
```

I want to be able to run that 30x concurrently. What tool/framework/library should I look at?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you run multiple programs in parallel from a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: Actually [How can I execute parallel "for" loops in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47786684) is a more specific duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running on the terminal. Run the `for` loop.

```
for run in {1..30}
do
  command &
done
```

`&` to run the process in the background, so you can continue to use the shell and do not have to wait until the script is finished

```
for run in {1..30}
do
/usr/local/bin/percona-playback --queue-depth 99999 --mysql-max-retries 0 --mysql-host somehost.xxx.com --mysql-username xxx --mysql-password xxxx --mysql-schema xxx --query-log-file some_slow_log.log &
done
```

Comment: That runs them sequentially, not concurrently.  Perhaps you meant `command &` instead of `;`.

Comment: Your first and last code blocks are still sequential, not using `&`

Comment: Your answer doesn't say that, and the question's "sample command" doesn't use `&`.  It's also not how bash's grammar works: `&` or `;` are separate from the command itself.  `for i in {1..30}; do true & done` is valid, `& ;` would also work but be redundant.  The key part of your answer is one character buried at the far right of the middle code block that would be very easy for most readers to miss.  But anyway, this question is a duplicate of [How can I execute parallel "for" loops in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47786684) so we can just close it instead of fixing your answer.

Comment: Anyhow, thanks for the recommendations. I fixed it.

Comment: Be aware that the bash overhead of launching another background thread is non-trivial.  If your query list is long enough, you can amortize the overhead enough to ignore it.